Quantum Espresso - Obtaining Negative Phonon Frequencies
I am new to using Quantum Espresso, I am trying to obtain the phonon dispersion for monolayer InSe. I have previously obtained the band structure with no issues. However, when I move to calculate phonon dispersion with ph.x I encounter negative frequencies which I know highlight an issue with the program. So far I have done the following:

Change the acoustic sum rule so that the start point for the acoustic modes is at zero
Change the convergence of the ph.x and pw.x (scf) calculation.
The input reads as follows:

PW.x (SCF)
&CONTROL 
title = 'InSe'
calculation = 'scf',
verbosity = 'high'
outdir = './',
pseudo_dir = '../Pseudopotentials',
prefix = 'InSe_Mono_out',
disk_io = 'high',
restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
/
&SYSTEM
ibrav = 4,
A = 4.050000289,
C = 30.0000021391,
nat = 4, ntyp = 2,
ecutwfc = 60,
ecutrho = 240,
occupations = 'tetrahedra_opt',
assume_isolated = '2D',
vdW_corr = 'dft-d3',
dftd3_threebody=.false.,
/
&ELECTRONS
diago_david_ndim = 4,
conv_thr = 1.D-16,
mixing_beta = 0.2,
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Se 34.00000 Se.pbe-dn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
In 49.00000 In.pbe-dn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS { angstrom }
In               2.0315915906        1.1775598796        1.3988623919
In               2.0315915906        1.1775598796       -1.3988623919
Se               0.0040008821        2.3481897174        2.6817409871
Se               0.0040008821        2.3481897174       -2.6817409871
K_POINTS { automatic }
12 12 1 0 0 0

d3hess.x
&INPUT
outdir = './',
prefix='InSe_Mono_out',   
/

Ph.x
&INPUTPH
outdir = './',
prefix='InSe_Mono_out',
verbosity = 'high',
fildyn='InSe.dyn',
fildrho='drho-InSe',
fildvscf='dv-InSe',
ldisp=.true.,
tr2_ph=1.0d-14
amass(1)=34.00
amass(2)=49.00
nq1=4,
nq2=4,      
nq3=1,   
/

q2r.x
&INPUT
fildyn = 'InSe.dyn',
flfrc='InSe.fc',
zasr='crystal'
/

matdyn.x
&INPUT
flfrc='InSe.fc',
flfrq='InSe.freq',
q_in_band_form=.true.,
q_in_cryst_coord=.true.,
asr='crystal',
amass(1)=34.00
amass(2)=49.00
/
4
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    100
0.6667 0.0000 0.0000    100
0.5000 0.2887 0.0000    100
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    1

The output gives the following, where one can see the issue with the bottom two modes close to the $\Gamma$-point. I understand this may be vague but as a new starter with phonon calculation I am wondering if there is something key I am missing
:

+1 and welcome to MMSE. Negative phonon frequency means imaginary frequency. Please see this answer. One of the most common reason of obtaining negative phonon frequency (which actually is imaginary frequency) in dynamically stable material is poor relaxation. If you are expecting all phonon frequency to be positive but still getting negative ones, see this answer to check the possible reasons.

Thank you very much for your reply. I understand a poor relaxation may be an issue, is this via completing say the vc-relax calculation in the pw.x in obtaining the lattice constants with the atomic positions? Or is this through the work that the calculation does that I mention above? Thanks in advance

The imaginary frequencies near $\Gamma$ point might be caused by the breaking of the Born-Huang invariance: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-022-00920-6.

@L_J what was your forc_conv_thr, etot_conv_thr in the vc-relax calculation? and how much force and stress are there after the relaxation? Poor relaxation or poor convergence will definitely be an issue

@ChengchengXiao Thankyou for this information I will look into thus

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine I set forc_conv_thr=0.5D-8 and etot_conv_thr=0.5D-9
